# Returning a Query Result to an ListView when joining tables Using Visual Basic and Linq

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, webforms, model-binding

Hello I can't seem to get his problem worked out. I have a ListView in an ASP.Net WebForms Application, I am using Model binding to get the data using the SelectMethod(). I have two Model Defined, Listed below,

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Namespace Models
Public Class tblSizes_
    <Key>
    Public Property Series() As Integer
    Public Property Description() As String
    Public Property EDPNum() As String
    Public Overridable Property tblUSSeries() As ICollection(Of tblUSSeries)
End Class
End Namespace

Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Namespace Models
Public Class tblUSSeries
    <Key>
    Public Property Series() As Integer
    Public Property Description() As String
    Public Overridable Property tblSizes_() As ICollection(Of tblSizes_)
End Class
End Namespace
```

In my GetSeries() method, I am joining the tblSizes_ table because I need to grab data from some columns in it, My method is posted below,

```
Public Function GetSeries(<QueryString("id")> searchString As String) As IQueryable(Of tblUSSeries)
    searchLabel.Text = searchString
    Dim pdb = New ProductDataContext()             
    Dim query As IQueryable(Of tblUSSeries) = 
                From a In pdb.tblUSSeries
                Join b In pdb.tblSizes_ On a.Series Equals b.Series
                Where a.Series.ToString().Equals(searchString) Or b.EDPNum.ToString().Equals(searchString)
                Select a
    Return query
End Function
```

My problem is that in the view I can get the two properties form the tblUSSeries table, but when I try to add a property from the tblSizes_ table I get an error  saying 'EDPNum' is not a memeber of 'E.Model.tblUSSeries'

```
<asp:ListView ID="seriesList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Series" GroupItemCount="1" ItemType="E.Models.tblUSSeries" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceholder1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder1" SelectMethod="GetSeries">
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <table id="emptyDataTable" runat="server">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>No data was returned.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <EmptyItemTemplate>
                            <td id="emptyItemTable" runat="server" />
                        </EmptyItemTemplate>
                        <GroupTemplate>
                            <div style="clear: both">
                                <div id="itemPlaceholder1" runat="server">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </GroupTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 100%">
                                <div style="font-size: 12px; float: left; width: 50px; padding-bottom: 10px; color: green">
                                    <%#:Item.Series%>
                                </div>
                                <div style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;  float: left; padding-right: 10px">
                                    <div >
                                        <%#:Item.Description%>
                                       </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;  float: left; padding-right: 10px">
                                    <div >
                                        <%#:Item.EDPNum%>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to implement a Group Join to retrieve the hierarchical model of your related collections

```
Public Function GetSeries(<QueryString("id")> searchString As String) As IQueryable(Of tblUSSeries)
    searchLabel.Text = searchString
    Dim pdb = New ProductDataContext()             
     Dim query As IQueryable(Of tblUSSeries) = 
            (From a In tblUSSeries
             Group Join b In tblSizes_ On a.Series Equals b.Series Into jTblSizes = Group
             Where a.Series.ToString().Equals(searchString) Or jTblSizes.Where(Function(p) p.EDPNum.ToString().Equals(searchString)).Any()
             Select New tblUSSeries With {.Series = a.Series, .Description = a.Description, .tblSizes_ = jTblSizes}
            ).AsQueryable().Cast(Of tblUSSeries)
    Return query
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Ciro, but that did not solve my problem, I am still getting the same error plus writing the query as you suggested I am getting an InValidCastException on the query.   An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in E.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_1`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[E.Models.tblUSSeries]'.

Comment: apologies, really I'm not used with VB.Net.. try now

Comment: Hey Ciro I changed that before you made the your changes, I know what you mean by using VB, I am a C# guy, but still the same results, I know in ASP MVC you can create a custom ViewModel class with the properties needed, should I just create it like that and get the data I need.

Comment: ok Psy, now you should avoid compiler error.. I did some test with LINQPad...  but I have some doubts about the join on the tblSizes_. Why do you join the two tables/collections if tblSizes_ it is a property of tblUSSeries?

Comment: (follows...) in my solution, I extract tblSizes that belong to each one item of tblUSSeries and not the joined tblsizes.. your join instead generates a relational projection on both the collections, and so you have duplicated tblUSSeries for each tblSizes_ collection item. For instance, your form shows your Model in a hierarchical (object) manner, and so there is a tblSeries_ collection for one tblUSSeries item..

Comment: Hey Psy, now you should have the solution, it missed a Group Join.. I updated solution in the answer